Change analogWrite() frequency using the arduino framework for SAMD51
I am using Adafruit Feather M4 Express board which has Atmel SAMD51 controller on it. I am using platformio as IDE, which lets me use this controller using the Arduino framework.
I want to change the frequency of my PWM signal which is generated with the analogWrite() function. Following the function analogWrite() takes me wiringanalog.c.
I am looking for some ideas on how to play around with the different frequency values.

analogWrite() does not control the frequency of the PWM, it change the duty cycle of a PWM signal with analogWrite(pin, duty_cycle). To change the frequency, it needs to alter the timer configuration that control the generation of the PWM signal. You might want to take a look at Secrets of PWM for basic idea.

@hcheung This link unfortunately does not show the information for the ATSAMD51 Cortex M4, which is on the Adafruit Feather M4 Express board that I am using. I was looking for something similar that allows the configuration of the frequency as well on the timer configuration.

I'm not provide you the code for copy-and-paste, it is a link for getting to understand the "basic idea" of what does it take to alter the frequency of a PWM signal.
